# Font Awesome code not rendering properly - slash being stripped

Tags: php, wordpress, font-awesome, divi

A PHP configuration issue I'm guessing.  We moved a client website from development to the client hosting (HostPapa), and the slashes are being stripped from the inline css Font Awesome codes,
so for example this:

```
content:"\f061";
```

becomes:

```
content:"f061";
```

which of course doesn't work.

The site is built with divi.

The font awesome code is placed in the text editor.

as (for example):

```
 <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

Divi generates the css as an inline style on the page like:

```
.fa-solid.fa-arrow-right:after{font-family:FontAwesome!important;font-weight:600!important;content:"\f061";
```

On the server where we're having the issue, its being generated as:

```
.fa-solid.fa-arrow-right:after{font-family:FontAwesome!important;font-weight:600!important;content:"f061";
```

The \ before the f061 is missing.

It's doing it under php 8.0 and various flavours of 7

I'm guessing there is something missing or extra in their php configuration, though can't think what it might be.

Any idea what module or configuration option could be doing that?

We've uploaded the site to multiple hosting platforms without issue.  It seems to be just something with the HostPapa config.

Comment: Stripped _where_? As in, what is the _PHP code_ which is outputting this CSS? Also possibly relevant: what PHP version is the hosting using?

Comment: How are the components being loaded/rendered? Please provide more details.